# Is the phrase "She needs to speak more confidently? incorrect?

Tags: adjectives

Is the phrase "She needs to speak more confidently"
correct?

Comment: Why do you think it might be incorrect?

Comment: It seems she needs to write more confidently.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. The verb in the sentence is 'needs'. 'To speak' is the "infinitive form" of a verb. Within a sentence, infinitives have the grammatical of nouns, however, and sorry because this gets tricky, they can function as the "head" of a lengthy noun phrase. **Within** a noun phrase they function as verbs and may still take objects and be modified by adverbs. So, 'to speak more confidently' is a noun phrase, but within it, the adverb 'more confidently' is modifying the verb 'to speak'.